# HTML arrangement of splitter panes is not right until first resize

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik

I have three Kendo().Splitters: the first is Vertical, dividing the top 10% of the screen from the bottom 90%.  Then, inside the upper pane I have a horizontal splitter that splits the left 25% of the screen from the rest; and in the lower pane, I have another horizontal splitter that also splits the left 25% of the screen from the rest.  The end result is four panes, the top left is 10% high and 25% wide, the top right is 10% high and 75% wide, the bottom left is 90% high and 25% wide, and the bottom right is 90% high and 75% wide.

I don't know that the splitters themselves have anything to do with my problem, but when the page first comes up, they do not line up.  The upper pane is split, like, 23%/77% while the lower pane is split 25%/75%.  The two vertical bars do not line up.  The first resize action I take (with my mouse) causes the panes to "snap" into position where, now, they do line up.

So, my question is, how is it best done to cause the (otherwise) finally-rendered page to do one more recalculation of all its parts?  I am assuming that this is what happens when I 
resize the page.  I have a `$(document).ready(function( )`, is there something I should add in there?

My environment is I.E. 9, Telerik controls, MVC4-Razor.

Comment: You could try maybe: `$(window).on('load',function(){$(this).resize();});`

Comment: This will work. If you want the credit, repost it as an answer and I'll take it.  My final solution was very similar:  `$(window).load(function () { $(window).resize(); });`